# RTMP live stream directly from NVENC encoder

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg-dash, libav, libx264

I am trying to create a live RTMP stream containing the animation generated with NVIDIA OptiX. The stream is to be received by nginx + rtmp module and broadcasted in MPEG-DASH format. Full chain up to dash.js player is working if the video is first saved to .flv file and then I send it with ffmpeg without any reformatting using command:

```
ffmpeg -re -i my_video.flv -c:v copy -f flv rtmp://x.x.x.x:1935/dash/test
```

But I want to stream directly from the code. And with this I am failng... Nginx logs an error "dash: invalid avcc received (2: No such file or directory)". Then it seems to receive the stream correctly (segments are rolling, dash manifest is there), however the stream is not possible to play in the browser.

I can see only one difference in the manifest between direct stream and stream from file. Codecs attribute of the representation in the direct stream is missed: codecs="avcc1.000000" instead of "avc1.640028" which I get when streaming from file.

My code opens the stream:

```
av_register_all();
AVOutputFormat* fmt = av_guess_format("flv",
file_name, nullptr);
fmt->video_codec = AV_CODEC_ID_H264;

AVFormatContext* _oc;
avformat_alloc_output_context2(&_oc, fmt, nullptr, "rtmp://x.x.x.x:1935/dash/test");

AVStream* _vs = avformat_new_stream(_oc, nullptr);
_vs->id = 0;
_vs->time_base = AVRational { 1, 25 };
_vs->avg_frame_rate = AVRational{ 25, 1 };

AVCodecParameters *vpar = _vs->codecpar;
vpar->codec_id = fmt->video_codec;
vpar->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
vpar->format = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
vpar->profile = FF_PROFILE_H264_HIGH;
vpar->level = _level;
vpar->width = _width;
vpar->height = _height;
vpar->bit_rate = _avg_bitrate;

avio_open(&_oc->pb, _oc->filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
avformat_write_header(_oc, nullptr);
```

Width, height, bitrate, level and profile I get from NVENC encoder settings. I also do the error checking, ommited here. Then I have a loop writing each encoded packets, with IDR frames etc all prepared on the fly with NVENC. The loop body is:

```
auto & pkt_data = _packets[i];
AVPacket pkt = { 0 };
av_init_packet(&pkt);
pkt.pts = av_rescale_q(_n_frames++, AVRational{ 1, 25 }, _vs->time_base);
pkt.duration = av_rescale_q(1, AVRational{ 1, 25 }, _vs->time_base);
pkt.dts = pkt.pts;
pkt.stream_index = _vs->index;
pkt.data = pkt_data.data();
pkt.size = (int)pkt_data.size();

if (!memcmp(pkt_data.data(), "\x00\x00\x00\x01\x67", 5))
{
    pkt.flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;
}

av_write_frame(_oc, &pkt);
```

Obviously ffmpeg is writing avcc code somewhere... I have no clue where to add this code so the RTMP server can recognize it. Or I am missing something else?

Any hint greatly appreciated, folks!

Comment: FLV output requires the AVCodecContext AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER flag enabled, which is then implemented by the encoder. See the ffmpeg wrapper for nvenc to see how this is handled and effect this in the OptiX encoder: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavcodec/nvenc.c

Comment: Thanks! I was really stuck on this issue for many days. With your linked code I could finally connect the pieces - all works perfectly now!

Comment: Can you please tell us the solution? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Gyan's comment I was able to solve the issue. Following the `AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER` flag in the [wrapper](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavcodec/nvenc.c) one can see how the global header is added, which was missing in my case. You can use directly the NVENC API function `nvEncGetSequenceParams`, but since I am anyway using SDK, it is a bit cleaner.

So I had to attach the header to `AVCodecParameters::extradata`:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> payload;
_encoder->GetSequenceParams(payload);
vpar->extradata_size = payload.size();
vpar->extradata = (uint8_t*)av_mallocz(payload.size() + AV_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE);
memcpy(vpar->extradata, payload.data(), payload.size());
```

`_encoder` is my instance of `NvEncoder` from SDK.

The [wrapper](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavcodec/nvenc.c) is doing the same thing, however using deprecated struct `AVCodecContext`.